# elementHandle.$x(expression) doesn't seem to be running relative to the elementHandle given

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

I have the following code getting the elementHandle for the "Buses" layer (out of a list of 32 different layers)

```
const [layerFound] = await page.$x("//div[@class='layer']/label[.='Buses']/..");
```

I then need to do some activation/validation on other elements within this 'layer' object. But this next line isn't grabbing the 'visible-toggle' object from the Buses layer, it's grabbing the one from the first layer of the list of 32 instead.

```
const [layerVis] = await layerFound.$x("//div[contains(@class, 'layer-option visible-toggle')]");
```

My understanding is elementHandle.$x(expression) evaluates the XPath expression relative to the elementHandle. But it is doing it relative to the page object.

There are many of these. The first being "Bridges". Which is the one being found/used.

```
<div class="layer">
  <label class="layer-label"><div>Buses</div></label>
  <div class="layer-option entity-count"><div>(629)</div></div>
  <div class="layer-option visible-toggle ">...</div>
  <div class="layer-option layer-preferences-toggle">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use a relative XPath: `const [layerVis] = await layerFound.$x(".//div[contains(@class, 'layer-option visible-toggle')]");` (dot before the XPath expression)

Comment: Oh right, that makes complete sense, but hard to find in any of the docs. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a relative XPath:

```
const [layerVis] = await layerFound.$x(".//div[contains(@class, 'layer-option visible-toggle')]");
```

(dot before the XPath expression)

Otherwise your XPath will search from the document root again.

Comment: The documents should not say it's relative to the element, when it is not without adding a `.`.  The code should prefix a `.` if it's not included, that would make it accurate.  Thank you for the answer.